# TypeError: execute_script() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, dom

I'm trying to use the Selenium method execute_script() to make a hidden Web element interactable for an automated UI test script, but I keep getting a type error where's it's complaining about an incorrect number of arguments.

```
TypeError: execute_script() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Here is the HTML markup for the input element I'm trying to manipulate:

```
<input id="button-file" type="file" accept=".docx" 
hidden>
<label for="button-file">
   <span class="MuiButtonBase-root css-w76rh" tabindex="0" role="button">
      "Upload"
      <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w123fg><\span>
   </span>
</label>
```

Here is the test code (Selenium Python) that is giving me the error:

```
element = self.webDriver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=Tags.uploadField)

self.webDriver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('hidden');", element)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  As far as I can tell, I'm passing two arguments: a script and a Web element.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've been trying to troubleshoot this problem.  I removed "element" from the arguments passed to execute_script() so that I'm only passing in a script, like so:

```
import_mission.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('hidden');")
```

and I got the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeAttribute')
```

I assumed executing this would unhide any element with the hidden attribute.

Comment: What is your version to python and selenium?

Comment: Selenium v4.1.3 and Python v3.7

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can:

```
driver.execute_script('''
  document.querySelector('#button-file').removeAttribute('hidden')
''')
```

That said though, I'm not sure hidden attribute even does anything for [type=file] inputs.